# Slicing a particular section from a string in Golang

Tags: go

I'm having a very long string with details of my employees, I just want to grab a particular section from that string and store it in a different string.
It looks something like this :

Employee Name       : Anjit

Working days        : 28

Extra Hours         : 72

Buddy Name          : Hemant

I only want to grab this portion for every employee from my string, but there are many entries like this in my string.
Someone help me out with this.

Comment: please edit your question and attach the raw string so I'll be able to help you.
any way you can slice it using split or regex (which more safe but more expensive performance wise)

Comment: Employee Number  :029789293 
Employee Name  :Anjit
Department  :Manufacturing

EcoPapery paperbags 
Order No. 909

Employee Number  :029789294 
Employee Name  :Hemant
Department  :Manufacturing

EcoPapery paperbags 
Order No. 910

Employee Number  :029789292
Employee Name  :Anjali
Department  :Food

EcoPapery paperbags 
Order No. 911

This is a portion of my string and i only want to slice the number name and department of employees and store it in different seperate variable for each employee

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called `slicing` and the easiest way (given a start and end positon of the substring you want) is to use `original[start:end]`.

Without seeing an example of the string, it is hard to provide guidance on good ways of finding the start and end of each substring that you want,

Comment: Employee Number  :029789293 
Employee Name  :Anjit
Department  :Manufacturing

EcoPapery paperbags 
Order No. 909

Employee Number  :029789294 
Employee Name  :Hemant
Department  :Manufacturing

EcoPapery paperbags 
Order No. 910

Employee Number  :029789292
Employee Name  :Anjali
Department  :Food

EcoPapery paperbags 
Order No. 911

This is a portion of my string and i only want to slice the number name and department of employees and store it in different seperate variable for each employee